# How to use python package in cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, pip, package

I installed package yolk with the help of pip

```
python -m pip install yolk
```

I want to use in cmd to do something like:

```
python -m yolk -l
```

I get:

```
No module named yolk.__main__; 'yolk' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Can I still run commands from this package in cmd? The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/yolk/) seems to imply that this is how you run this package?

Answer (score 1):

> `python -m yolk -l`
>
> The documentation seems to imply that this is how you run this package?

That is not what the documentation says. It says to use the console script `yolk` directly. But indeed it is always better to call the *executable module* instead, so after looking at the code, it seems to be:

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m yolk.cli
```

Answer (score -1):

yolk seems to be available only on python 2

```sh
python --version  # check python 2
pip install virtualenv  # install virtual environment on python 2
virtualenv venv  # create your virtual environment
source venv/bin/activate  # activate it
pip install yolk  # install the package
yolk -v  # use yolk's package bin commands
# ... other commands with yolk
deactivate  # virtual environment
```